# General Question about silverlight ... Classes instance and shared memory

Tags: silverlight

I wrote simple silverlight web application using the default ASP test page.

If there are 10 users that connecting together to this web application => the silverlight will create 10 thread ( one for each user ) right ?

If this is right ... is there some option to create some shared memory to all of those instances ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight applications, unlike ASP.NET applications, are downloaded and executed locally on the client's machine, so there is no way to share memory, or anything at all, directly between the instances.